# How to add both Done and Return button to a multiline EditTextView?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

**Objective:** 
My goal is to have an `EditTextView` that includes Both "`Done`" button and `carriage return`.

**What is the catch?**
Well, the problem here is that my `EditTextView` must be multiline, but also implement the done button.

**What have you tried?**
Good question here is what I have tried:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/messageToSend"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="68dp"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:hint="@string/messageToSend"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textImeMultiLine" />
```

Maybe I have the wrong approach here, I just want to be able to dissmiss the keyboard when finishing typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that you will have *any* buttons. You cannot force the IME to provide any buttons, or force the IME to provide specific buttons. What happens on a multiline `EditText` widget when you request `actionDone` is up to the IME implementation. There are hundreds of these, few if any of which were written by you.

Hence, I would focus on making your app usable regardless of whether there is a "Done" button, since there very well may not be a "Done" button, regardless of how you structure the `<EditText>` element.

Personally, I would expect any IME that showed a "Done" button in lieu of a carriage return button in this case to be broken. Some IMEs may show both, but I would expect those to be few in number.

Comment: I kind of figure that I was not on the right track, please advice for a way to disable the keyboard without done button, the keyboard is hiding my layout includinga submit button just under the EditTextView

Comment: @meda: "please advice for a way to disable the keyboard without done button" -- this is not possible. Your users choose which IME they wish to use, and the IME developers choose whether to show a Done button. "the keyboard is hiding my layout includinga submit button just under the EditTextView" -- then fix your layout (e.g., wrap it in a `ScrollView`) or fix your manifest (e.g., use `adjustPan`). See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html